# c++/cli Read text file

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I am trying to read in a text file into my program so that I can populate my mysql database that I have connected to my program.  Before I can send it to the database I need to be able to read in each string one by one instead of reading the entire line.  I am new to using visual c++ and forms so any help would be appreciated.

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

    String^ fileName = "customerfile.txt";
    try 
    {
        MessageBox::Show("trying to open file {0}...", fileName);
        StreamReader^ din = File::OpenText(fileName);

        String^ str;
        int count = 0;
        while ((str = din->ReadLine()) != nullptr)  
        {
            count++;
            MessageBox::Show(str);
        }
    }
```

The text file that I am trying to read from is formatted like this:

43 john smith 4928 orchard rd. miami florida

I would like the message box to show 43, then a new message box to show john, and so on.  Right now it displays the entire line.

Comment: It's C++/CLI.  I am using it to make forms and I can't use c#

Comment: Then why did your question say C++ lol

Comment: @machine_hed, please provide a minimal code that demonstrates the problem  and describe it more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

[Parse Strings Using the Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3awe53k.aspx)

```
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
//...

String^ fileName = "customerfile.txt";
StreamReader^ din = File::OpenText(fileName);

String^ delimStr = " ,.:\t";
array<Char>^ delimiter = delimStr->ToCharArray();

String^ str;
int count = 0;
while ((str = din->ReadLine()) != nullptr)
{
    count++;

    array<String^>^ words;
    words = str->Split(delimiter);
    for (int word = 0; word<words->Length; word++)
    {
        if (!words[word]->Length) // skip empty words
            continue;
        Trace::WriteLine(words[word]);
    }

}
```

You can set `delimStr = " ";` if you just want to split using blank space. If you want to split using space and comma `,` then change it to `delimStr = " ,";` and so on.